# Need to control width of the table column in print

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, printing, html-table

I am using Bootstrap in my Visualforce Page and the table looks alright when the Vf Page is generated.

I need to print this using ctrl+P, but when one of the column values (name) was going too large, the table was getting truncated in print.

So I added the table fixed layout and word-wrap.

Now it works alright, however now all the columns are of equal width giving the serial number and name as the same width, which looks awkward.

Image of table in the link

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAwV2.png)

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:#00205b">
                    <th style="color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#bf0d3e;" rowspan="2">#</th>
                    <th style="color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#bf0d3e;" rowspan="2">Employee/Dependent</th>
                    <th style="color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#bf0d3e;" rowspan="2">Relationship</th>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap }" var="planName">
                        <th style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center;" colspan="2" rowspan="1">{!planName}</th>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color:#00205b">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap}" var="planMeta">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap[planMeta]}" var="planMetavalue">
                            <th style="color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#bf0d3e;" rowspan="1">{!planMetavalue}</th>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!qliWrapperMainList}" var="qliWrapperlist">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!qliWrapperlist}" var="qliWrapper">
                        <tr style="background-color:#fafafa">
                            <td>{!qliWrapper.seq_number}</td>
                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(qliWrapper.relation==null)}">
                                <td>{!qliWrapper.Name}</td>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(qliWrapper.relation!=null)}">
                                <td style="padding-left:20px;">-&nbsp;{!qliWrapper.Name}</td>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                            <td>{!qliWrapper.relation}</td>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap}" var="planMain">
                                <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap[planMain]}" var="mapSubPlan">
                                    <td>${!qliWrapper.planMap[planMetadataMap[planMain][mapSubPlan]]}</td>
                                </apex:repeat>
                                </apex:repeat>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-bottom-color:#533278;"></td>
                        <td style="border-bottom-color:#533278;"></td>
                        <td style="border-bottom-color:#533278;text-align:right">Family Total</td>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap}" var="planMain">
                            <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap[planMain]}" var="mapSubPlan">
                                <td style="border-bottom-color:#533278;text-align:right">${!qliWrapperlist[0].planTotal[planMetadataMap[planMain][mapSubPlan]]}</td>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Code added for the Print:-

```
<style>
@media print {
.table th { word-wrap: break-word;  background-color: #eeeeee 
   !important; color: #333333 !important; }
          .table td { word-wrap: break-word;  background- 
          color: #ffffff !important; color: #333333 
        !important; }
.table { table-layout: fixed !important; }
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could set the with of any td to XYZ if you want to.
Then the word would break and the table fits on the printing margins.

As example:

```
<style>
@media print {
    .table th { 
        word-wrap: break-word;  
        background-color: #eeeeee !important;
        color: #333333 !important; 
    }
    .table td {
        max-width:10%;
        background-color: #ffffff !important;
        color: #333333 !important; 
    }
    .table { 
        table-layout: fixed !important; 
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it's still taking the same width for all the columns. are you suggesting to add specific width to the first serial number column, how to do that?

Comment: yeah, if you set a class for every colum, you can set the width of every colum ;)